# How to display Text after an Image on a new line left aligned, instead of wrapping around the image?

Tags: html, css, css-float, text-align

This is my code:

```
<P>
<div><img style="border: 0pt none; float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;" src="Image.jpeg" alt="Image" width="150" height="150" />This is text wrapped around Image</div>
</P>
<P>
<div>
<h2 align="left">This text should left align</h2>
</div>
</P>
```

I want to display "This text should left align" as aligned left side in a new line

I used **Div** and **P** tags for this, If there's something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML needs some work - you cant have a `h2` inside a `p`. However, if i understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
<div>
    <img style="float:left;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" 
         src="Image.jpeg" alt="Image" width="150" height="150" />
    This is text wrapped around Image
</div>

<h2 style="clear:left;">This text should left align</h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g08hycaf/

Comment: Wow, that's exactly how I wanted it. Thank you so much brother

Comment: My pleasure - do tick the answer as correct :) and practice more on your html - enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Clear:both should do the job

```
<div>
<div><img style="border: 0pt none; float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;" src="Image.jpeg" alt="Image" width="150" height="150" />This is text wrapped around Image</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both">
<h2 align="left">This text should left align</h2>
</div>
```